# How to make list into set with same sequence? (python)

Tags: python

I have a file which I am using for brute-force attacks so I want to get rid of the duplicates to save some time and copy it into another file without ruining sequence. I can make another list and append it and then check if it'= is in there but file is large so I do not think it is best way to do this. What I tried is:

```
with open('original_file.txt','r') as file:
   words = file.readlines()

with open('file_without_duplicates','w') as file:
   for i in set(words): file.write(i)
```

I have most common words at the beginning so sequence is important but this example ruins it.

Comment: You can use `f.writelines(set(words))`

Comment: @PuryaJafari How does that solve the problem of `set()` losing the order of the original list?

Comment: He said file is large. i thought it would helps at another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use a set, but in a different way.

Make a new empty set and use that to keep track of words that have been written to the file.  For each word in the original list, if it's not already in the set, then write it to the file and add it to the set.

```
written_words = set()
with open('file_without_duplicates','w') as file:
    for i in words:
        if i not in written_words:
            file.write(i)
            written_words.add(i)
```

Comment: Yeah, but it contains like billions of passwords so it has to check every one of them every time it needs to add a word, so is there another way like making list into set without "shuffling" it

Comment: Checking if an item is in a set is very fast.  I don't see any better solution.

Comment: just combine this solution with the one by sunnytown (which is currently "wrong", it should use a set)

Answer (score 0):

If the file is large, you can avoid loading it all into memory by reading and instantly writing line by line. Use a list to keep track of which words have been written already and check for every new word, if it's not yet in that list.

```
written = []
with open('original_file.txt','r') as file_input:
    with open('file_without_duplicates','w') as file_output:
        for word in file_input:
            if word not in written:
                file_output.write(word)
                written.append(word)
```

Comment: You should use a `set` instead of a list for `written`. You can combine two `with` statements into one to avoid unnecessary nesting: `with a as b, c as d:`.

Answer (score 0):

This combines the answers by John Gordon and sunnytown. Access to the set is essentially O(1), i.e., it happens in constant time, and this time is very short. Other than the set, nothing else is kept in memory.

```
written = set()
with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    for word in infile:
        if word not in written:
            outfile.write(word)
            written.add(word)
```

Answer (score -1):

- ******Python >= 3.6******
  `Dictionary` is ordered by default

```
with open('original_file.txt','r') as file:
   words = file.readlines()

from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_words = {i:None for index in words}


with open('file_without_duplicates','w') as file:
   for i in ordered_words: file.write(i)
```

- ******Python < 3.6******

You can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
with open('original_file.txt','r') as file:
   words = file.readlines()

from collections import OrderedDict
ordered_dict = OrderedDict({i:None for i in words})


with open('file_without_duplicates','w') as file:
   for i in ordered_dict: file.write(i)
```

`OrderedDict` preserves the order of the words

Comment: `enumerate` is pretty superfluous, no? Just `{i: None for i in words}` would do just fine. But in fact, you creating a dict comprehension first negates the point of an OrderedDict.

Comment: any dict since Python 3.6 is insertion ordered

Comment: Yep now I think about it , you are correct , `enumerate` is redundant

Comment: @WalterTross - I was under the impression , its from 3.8 , but if thats the case , the good old `dict` would do as well , let me modify the answer to accomodate that

Comment: actually it's in the language specs since 3.7, in 3.6 it's guaranteed only by the CPython implementation (the most common one)